# Visual Studio for Macで「行の複製」のショートカットを設定するには？

Tags: macos, visual-studio

**Cmd＋D** に設定したいです。

[VisualStudioで行複製をCtrl+Shift+Dでできますか？ - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/213085)

にある **Keyboard Shortcuts Manager** というもののMac版があればいいのですが。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくインストールと設定だけで出来るようなものは「今は無い」と思われます。

参照記事の回答にも書いてある通り、元々Windows版VidualStudioに「行の複製」の機能があるからショートカットを割り当てることが出来ると考えられます。
[VisualStudioで行複製をCtrl+Shift+Dでできますか？](https://teratail.com/questions/213085)

> 4.`Commaond`に`Edit.Duplicate`、`Scope`に`テキストエディタ`、`Shortcut`で`CTRL+SHIFT+D`を入力、`Add Shortcut`して`Close`する

Visual Studio の既定のキーボード ショートカット
[編集](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#bkmk_edit)

> Edit.Duplicate **Ctrl** + **D**

Visual Studio for Mac の既定のキーボード ショートカット
[編集](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/mac/keyboard-shortcuts?view=vsmac-2019#edit)
Default keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio for Mac
[Edit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/keyboard-shortcuts?view=vsmac-2019#edit)

Mac版では日本語/英語どちらのページでも編集機能に行の複製(Duplicate)に関する項目は有りません。

---

代替出来る機能としてのマクロ機能はVisualStudio2012で削除されていて、それを補うExtensionもWindows版はあってもMac版は無い状況です。

[Visual Studio Community 2013でマクロ機能を使う](http://jirolabo.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/11/114443)

> マクロの記録・再生機能は Visual Studio 2012 で廃止されてしまいました。
> ただし、Visual Studio (Community) 2013で拡張機能をインストールすることでマクロ機能が使えます。

その拡張機能の現在はこれですが、MacOSに対応している(Tagsリストにmacosが有る)という情報はありません。
[Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)

というよりVisual Studio for Mac用の拡張機能は非常に少なく8個しかありません。
[tag:macosを指定して検索した結果](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=tag%3Amacos&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance)

ちなみにWindows版でもマクロ機能の復活を望む声は有るようですが、実現性は乏しそうです。
[Macros for Visual Studio VS2019](https://developercommunityapi.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/idea/477471/macros-for-visual-studio-vs2019.html)

---

無ければ自分で作ってしまえという情報がこの記事の回答に書かれています。
[Visual Studio : short cut Key : Duplicate Line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2279000/9014308)

> **Macro solution (pre VS2017)**
> If you'd like to implement a more complete solution, perhaps to create a simpler keyboard shortcut or you don't want to effect the clipboard, see this guide:
>
> より完全なソリューションを実装したい場合、より単純なキーボードショートカットを作成したい場合、またはクリップボードに影響を与えたくない場合は、次のガイドを参照してください。

「次のガイドを参照してください。」で紹介されているリンクは今は存在しないようです。
しかし、そのVisualBasicによる内容はコピーされているので、それを参考に自分で作ることは出来るかもしれません。

---

あとはWindows版には機能があるわけですから、それをMac版にも移植して欲しいと要望を出しておいて、実現される様なら気長に待つということも考えられます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！今の時点では、なかなかすぐには出来ないようですね。